# Open new window in new tab

Tags: angular, typescript, tabs, window

I am trying to open a new window when user click on button as follows:

```
protected assignActity(type: string): void {
    var window = window.open('/#/link');
    this.Service.assignActivity(type).subscribe(res => {
      window.location = '/#/link/' + res;
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
```

but it's throwing an error:

```
core.umd.js:3468 TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
```

How to correct it to get it working?

Comment: `window.open('some url');` will work but if you want to use angular-universal you'd avoid to manipulate window directly.

Comment: so it will possible or not

Comment: I have that requirement, so if you have any workaround please suggest

Comment: I'm not used to angular-universal but I've seen that you can access to a variable `isBrowser` (from what I remember). So use DI to inject this variable in your app so you can use it from anywhere. Then, when you have to use `window.open` just wrap it like that : `if (isBrowser) { window.open('some url) }`

Comment: @Rhushikesh , I am struggling with popup opening requirement in angular2 application with mvc can you plz provide the sample code how are you opening the browser popup window in your application.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The reason for `window` variable being `undefined` is the fact that **you have declared a variable named window again in the local scope**.

According to the scoping rules of `javascript/typescript`, before the global variable is accessed, the local variables value is looked up. 
Also when you initially declare a variable, it is set to undefined, Hence the error message you receive.

So all you have to do is simply change the variable name in which you capture the opened tab's reference

```
var newWindow = window.open('some_url');
```

However this is not the recommended approach as angular2 apps can run in a variety of environments such as mobile or be rendered server side where `window` object may or may not be available. Not to mention it would be very hard to mock the window object in tests

Instead you can wrap the `window` object in a service and inject that service into your component. This way you can simply substitute the *service* implementation according to the environment, using  *Dependency injection*

**The service file**

```
@Injectable()
export class WindowRef {
    constructor() {}

    getNativeWindow() {
        return window;
    }
}
```

**The component file**

```
@Component({
  selector : 'demo',
  template : '<div> Demo </div>'
})
class DemoComponent {

   nativeWindow: any
   constructor( private winRef: WindowRef ) { 
       this.nativeWindow = winRef.getNativeWindow();
   }

    protected assignActity(type: string): void {
       var newWindow = this.nativeWindow.open('/#/link');
       this.Service.assignActivity(type).subscribe(res => {

       newWindow.location = '/#/link/' + res;
       console.log(res);
    })
}
```

Comment: not working for me, Do i need to call it in provider in module file?

Comment: @HidaytRahman yes. you need to call it in provider in module file