# Open an external URL from within Angular Component

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a `http get` call within my angular app that returns a link to a `dropbox` file.

Once I receive that file I want it to be automatically opened within a new browser tab.

**I have tried this:**

```
window.open(data, "_blank");
```

The above opens the link within my localhost like so:

```
http://localhost:3000/dropboxLinkHere
```

After doing some research I have found that you cannot external links from within angular routes.

Does anyone know how this could be achieved?

Comment: which angular version are you using ?

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI angular version `5.0.1`

Comment: Not the same problem you have, but this answer explains how to approach handling a window inside Angular https://stackoverflow.com/a/40771732/614277

Comment: @AbderrahmaneTAHRIJOUTI thanks for the link. this helps. learned something new actually.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried window.open(dropboxLinkHere,"_blank"); and it worked for me.It has to be the complete link including http or https part. Could you please verify the data(response) from your get call? 
For example, "www.google.com" took me within localhost like in your question. However "http://www.google.com" and "http://google.com" worked well for me.

Comment: Thanks for the help. You pointed me in the correct direction I had `double quotes` around my link. After removing them its working fine.

Comment: @Skywalker Sure. Happy to help :)

Comment: Just a suggestion these kind of answers should be put as comments. Otherwise you can get downvoted. I've made the same mistake before :) [heres a link to the help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Again thanks for the help. Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Comment: @Skywalker Sure. Thank you! :) Will be careful from now on.