# Concat angular var in js function

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I need concatenate "proposal.id" in the first parameter on function window.open. My code look like this:

```
<button ion-button color="light" onclick="window.open('https://mywebsite.com/offer?id={{ proposal.id }}', '_self')">Offert</button>
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here's what you should try. We need to break this down in to markup and controller logic:

Markup:

```
<button ion-button color="light" ng-click="openMyWindow()">Ofertar</button>
```

Controller:

You would have inject 'window' to your controller (if you already haven't)

```
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $window) {

    $scope.openMyWindow= function() {
        $window.open('https://mywebsite.com/offer?id=' + proposal.id, '_self');
    };
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nope, this return a error:

Binding to event property 'onclick' is disallowed for security reasons, please use (click)=...
If 'onclick' is a directive input, make sure the directive is imported by the current module. .... blablabla

Comment: If you are using ```Angular``` then ```window``` must be ```undefined```  Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760099/how-to-open-new-window-in-new-tab-in-angular2

Comment: exists a similar function on Angular to redirect a external url, wich can be placed on the html tag?

Comment: Check the edited answer. It works in my test code without an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button ion-button color="light" onclick="window.open('https://mywebsite.com/offer?id=' + {{ proposal.id }}, '_self')">Offert</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i try this:

I create a new function in "mypage.ts" named "openlink()"

"mypage.html" look like this:

```
<button ion-button color="light" (click)="openLink(proposal.id)">Offer</button>
```

And the file "mypage.ts"

```
openLink(proposal){
    window.open("https://mywebsite/offer?id=" + proposal, "_self");
}
```

Thanks erveryone , your responses has opened my way hehe!